# Python Relative Import within Brother/Sister Folder for AWS CodeBuild

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-codebuild

I am building on AWS CodeBuild using Python 2.7, but I believe this is much more a generic python import problem. I have a directory setting, shown below. I am running test.py inside the test folder. I would like to import the dependency mainScript.py as part of this testing. However, I cannot seem to get the relative dependencies right and I am having a lot of difficulty importing the mainScript within the test folder. Below is a layout of my directory folder

```
main
    src
       mainScript.py
    test
       test.py
```

If for example my directory setup was something like

```
main
    test
       test.py
       mainScript.py
```

I could have my import be done the following way

```
from mainScript import *
```

I have confirmed this works. But, I like it in its own src folder. I have tried all these These are the following relative path attempts I have tried

```
from ..src/mainScript import * #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
from ..src.mainScript import * #ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
from mainScript import * #ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainScript'
from src.mainScript import * #ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
from src/mainScript import * #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have been struggling for a bit and I couldn't quite find a question with someone asking about accessing a brother/sister folder script. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding the **init**.py files. It ended up being that I had to run python with the -m argument in my command, which was added in Python 2.4.

[PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/)

> Python 2.4 adds the command line switch -m to allow modules to be
>   located using the Python module namespace for execution as scripts.
>   The motivating examples were standard library modules such as pdb and
>   profile, and the Python 2.4 implementation is fine for this limited
>   purpose.

So the command to launch from the top directory is:

```
python -m test.test
```

This seems to work and get the right namespace. Then in your test.py file you would import the mainScript the following way

```
from src.mainScript import *
```

Answer (score 2):

Python treats directories as packages if they contain a `__init__.py` file. Updating your structure to the following should do the trick:

```
    __init__.py
    src
       __init__.py
       mainScript.py
    test
       __init__.py
       test.py
```

Now, from test.py, you could do `from ..src import *`. For more details on **init**.py, you can look here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)